# iCarousel space the carousel items and Hide the items in the background

Tags: ios, icarousel

I am looking at use the iCarouselTypeRotary. I want to space the items so there is a gap of x value between them, but also that the views that are not the front 3 views are hidden.

I have tried

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
//customize carousel display
    switch (option)
    {
        case iCarouselOptionShowBackfaces:
            return NO;
        case iCarouselOptionSpacing:
        {
            //add a bit of spacing between the item views
            return value * 1.2f;
        }
         default:
        {
        return value;
        }
    }
}
```

but this is only spaces the views, it doesn't hide the background items.

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
You have add one more case in your switch case for only visible 3 views at a time and remaining will be invisible

- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
//customize carousel display
    switch (option)
    {
        case iCarouselOptionShowBackfaces:
        {
            return NO;
        }
        case iCarouselOptionSpacing:
        {
            //add a bit of spacing between the item views
            return value * 1.2f;
        }
        case iCarouselOptionVisibleItems:
        {
           return 3;
        }
        default:
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```